# Non asymptotic error bound for$f(x)=\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$

Tags: regression, nonparametric, estimators, histogram

I am considering the following model:
$(X_i,Y_i)_{i=1}^n$ are iid random pairs with $X_i\in[0,1]$ and $Y_i\in\mathbf{R}$. Let $f(x)=\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$. Consider an estimate $\hat{f}_n$ of $f$.

Under some hypothesis on $f$ (such as Holder), I am looking for a result providing an upper bound (as good as possible) on $\Vert\hat{f}_n-f\Vert_\infty$ with high probability.

I am particularly interested in the case of the regressogram:

Let $I_1,\dots,I_K$ be the regular partition of the unit interval. Suppose $x\in I_k$, then
$$\hat{f}_n(x) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i1(X_i\in I_k)}{\sum_{i=1}^n1(X_i\in I_k)}.$$

Is there any reference?